# calling a function with a char and a variable number of arguments

Tags: ios, objective-c

so what i am trying to do is whenever i touch a button, it calls a function with both a char and some variable number of arguments (in this case two ints that are both worth 24).

```
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender {
number = 24;

printf_to_debug("some text %d %d ",number, number);
//printf(" %d %d ",number, number);
}
```

however, when i call the function it seems to always change my ints to some big number, which i don't understand.

```
void printf_to_debug (char* fmt, ...) {

va_list args;
va_start( args, fmt );

printf(fmt, args);

charString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String: fmt];
charString = [NSString stringWithFormat:charString, args];
debugTextString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\r%@",charString, debugTextString];

va_end( args );


}
```

does anyone see a problem with my code?

Comment: can you add the output of this code when you run it along with what `nslog(@"%@",debugTextString)` prints?

Comment: Why do you pass `debugTextString` as the last argument to the line that gets assigned to `debugTextString`? That makes no sense.

Comment: What's the data type of `number`?

Comment: i pass debugtextstring again because i want to add it on to make it longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `vprintf()` to print the arguments given by a `va_list`:

```
va_list args;
va_start (args, fmt );
vprintf(fmt, args);
va_end( args );
```

The corresponding `NSString` method is `initWithFormat:arguments:`:

```
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@(fmt) arguments:args];
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a look at what your code actually does.

The first important line is: `printf_to_debug("some text %d %d ",number, number);`

Which looks fine, it doesn't really matter what number is it'll be treated as an `int` anyways.

Next you initialize the variable arguments list which is fine but then you try and print using: 
`printf(fmt, args);`

Now, When you use that code, you seem to want printf to treat each individual object in your variable arguments list as a separate parameter, however, printf doesn't care. All it sees is that you passed it a parameter. It doesn't know or care what the parameter was, all it knows and cares about is that you told it to treat the first parameter it was given as a decimal number (that's what the "%d" says). So now, it takes va_list and treats it as a number and prints it. Since you only provided one argument, the second number you get is complete garbage, and I suspect XCode tried to warn you about that (command line clang does).

Now for the simple solution:

When your trying to print a variable arguments list as seperate objects use the vprintf function. So in your case it would be `vprintf(fmt, args);`